# Requirements for a fluorescent medium to provide optical gain

Tags: optics, laser, fluorescence

I have seen fluorescent material such as Rhodamine 6G being used as a gain medium in dye lasers. My understanding is that by pumping the medium with energy, we can make stimulated emission happen instead of the spontaneous process of fluorescence (when we achieve population inversion). What are the requirements for a fluorescent material to be used as an optical gain medium? For example, could I use something like Olive oil to act as a gain medium? If not, why not?